# Can I use more than 2 cores for a Blazor Wasm AOT Publish Build in VS2022?

Tags: blazor, webassembly, aot

During my publish build, the CPU usage is 50%. The build takes about half an hour, so I wanted to test it with more cores. I tried `dotnet publish --configuration Release --aot --runtime wasm --readytorun --maxparallelism 4 -o ./bin/release/net7.0/browser-wasm/publish` but there was the error message "Unknown switch --aot". Probably, I do not need `--aot`, because my project file contains

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <RunAOTCompilation>true</RunAOTCompilation>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When I delete `--aot`, the error message is almost the same: "Unknown switch --readytorun". So, I added `<RunReadyToRun>true</RunReadyToRun>` to the PropertyGroup and deleted `--readytorun`. Now the error message is "Unknown switch --maxparallelism". I deleted `--maxparallelism` and added `<MaxParallelism>4</MaxParallelism>` to the PropertyGroup but I think this is simply ignored as `<MaxParallelism>` does not exist.
Is there a way, to achieve compilation with 4 cores?

Comment: All the errors tell you there are no such switches. There's no `--aot`, `--readytorun` or `--maxparallelism`. `ReadyToRun` etc are *properties* and can be set with `--p:PropertyName=value`

Comment: That's what I thought and why I moved them to the PropertyGroup. Is there a way to use more cores anyway.

Comment: It's already multicore. `the CPU usage is 50%` that means that 2 cores are used in a 4-core system, or all cores are used but 50% of the work is IO-related. Did you check the Task manager's CPU and IO graphs during publishing? You can control parallelism using the *correct* switches. As the [dotnet publish docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#msbuild) `The dotnet publish command calls MSBuild` and `Any parameters passed to dotnet publish are passed to MSBuild.` The parallelism switch is `-m`. You can try using `-m:4`

Comment: I tried `dotnet publish --configuration Release --runtime wasm --p:MaxParallelism=4 -o ./bin/release/net7.0/browser-wasm/publish` now and the CPU usage was up to 80%. Then I tried the default publish from the VS GUI again and the CPU usage went up to 60%. There must be a difference between these two methods, because with the first one, more files a created. So, what would be the prompt for getting the same output? My GUI config is: Configuration: Release, Target Framework: net7.0, Deployment Mode: Self-contained, Target Runtime: browser-wasm, "Ahead-of-tim (AOT) compilation" is checked?